# json-server: Default JSON for non-matching route

Tags: json-server

I want to fake a login API with the route */api/login/:userName/:password* that would return `{ "success": false, "userName": "", "password": "" }` in case `userName` or `password` is not found in the database. How can I achieve this with json-server?

So far I have this database JSON:

```
{
   "login": [
      { "success": true, "userName": "zaphod", "password": "galaxy" }
   ],
   "invalidLogin": [
      { "success": false, "userName": "", "password": "" }
   ]
}
```

invalidLogin is currently not used and should be used for every login route with unknown `userName` or `password`.

This is my *server.js*:

```
const jsonServer = require('json-server');
const server = jsonServer.create();
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json');
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();

server.use(middlewares);

// Rewrite rules
server.use(jsonServer.rewriter({
   '/login/:userName/:password': "/login?userName=:userName&password=:password"
}))

server.use('/api', router);

server.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('JSON Server is running')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something like this using `router.render` function:

```
router.render = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.path === '/login') {
    if (res.locals.data.length !== 0) {
      res.jsonp(res.locals.data);
    } else {
      res.jsonp([
        { "success": false, "userName": "", "password": "" }
      ])
    }
  } else {
    res.jsonp(res.locals.data);
  }
}
```

Basically this router code will check if there are non-empty response to `/login/.../...` and afterwards replace it with error JSON on empty login request. You can upgrade this mock's logic further.

Aforementioned code can be placed after rewrite rules in *server.js* (there was a minor error in your code, you have to write it with `api`, [reference issue](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/518)):

```
server.use('/api', jsonServer.rewriter({
   "/login/:userName/:password": "/login?userName=:userName&password=:password",
}))
```